# How important is visually indicating that ListBox items are drag-dropable in an application where not every List has this functionality?

Tags: lists, drag-n-drop, affordance

We're building an application with various modules a great deal of which involves browses with lists of items (not unlike the list of questions here on Stack Exchange).
One of the modules (thus far) involves a page/view with a few lists next to each other that allows you to drag items between said lists fairly similar to Trello (like so):

[image]

The core of my question is that Trello has no real visual indication that you can drag and drop these cards (possibly because it's a primary feature of the webapp itself?), so does there need to be some indication (e.g. skeuomorphic grip dots that appear on mouse-over for each item) that our own list items can be dragged and dropped?

Some small additional things to consider are that this is a line of business app that will be used on an all-day-every-day kind of basis so once users are aware list items are draggable in this scenario that's pretty much it.

Another is that we're considering extending the drag-drop UX to a few other areas of the application now we've got the actual code in a state it's fairly easy to attach to things, but this extension will appear on an 'as and when it's useful' basis.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Please consider marking your question answered. Should you need more information, please feel free to edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is **very important** to distinguish draggable items **because** not all items have the drag functionality.

I agree with your suggestion to at least show *some indication* that items are draggable. This is most often achieved by having the drag icon appear when hovering over a draggable element:

[image]

I think adding **another** visual indicator will help **solidify** that draggable indication to the user.

Here are some examples!

[Drag Icon and Background Color Change On Hover](http://draggabilly.desandro.com/)

[Drag Icon and Dotted Border Change On Hover](http://jsfiddle.net/pbu0qad1/)

Answer (score 0):

drag'n'drop nearly always has bad affordance.

The current model in gmail is the following:

gmail's new dd affordance

Albeit I'm not sure if they're really serious about it, esp. as it only appears to the hovered element.

The previous one was this:

gmail's old dd affordance

More dragg-ish, but still bad.

I think in order to reach good affordance with a drag-n-drop control, it either has to be explicit action (up and down arrows, that's pretty explicit), or it has to be "bumpy" (in case of a touchscreen): I guess the apple version looks more like a kind of air venting holes than something to get a hold on.

Reference : [Is Apple's or Google's meaning of the three-horizontal-bar icon more popular?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/25030/is-apples-or-googles-meaning-of-the-three-horizontal-bar-icon-more-popular/25032#25032)