# Apple's Hamburger Menu?

Tags: menu, apple, hamburger

Does anybody know why Apple uses two horizontal lines for hamburger menu vs three horizontal lines?

Comment: Your question is somewhat generic. Could you give info as to why your asking the question?

Comment: Trying not to be the same maybe?

Comment: Apple first off like to do the same thing as everyone else but with there spin on it. Also 2 lines create an X better as a close button than 3 lines. So it can be to do with that. Also means its just a bun now not a hamburger

Answer (score 2):

I think if using 2 lines will make the transformation into "X" more make sense than using 3 lines, which is in IOS it self 3 lines has a meaning already.

[image]

[Is Apple's or Google's meaning of the three-horizontal-bar icon more popular?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/25030/is-apples-or-googles-meaning-of-the-three-horizontal-bar-icon-more-popular)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand where the question arises from.

Apple technically doesn't have any guidelines for Hamburger menus. If you check out the 
[iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/design-principles/) you won't find any guidelines for hamburger menus because iOS apps based on the guidelines don't have any.

If somehow Apple were to use a Hamburger menu, it would be in the [Navigation Bar](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-bars/navigation-bars/), but of course, there isn't any. What Apple uses instead for navigation is called a [Tab Bar](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-bars/tab-bars/) (something akin to [Bottom Navigation](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html) on Android) for quick navigation among the various screens. Also, Apple recommends using only 3-5 navigation item in the Tab Bar.

> **Avoid having too many tabs.** Each additional tab reduces the tappable area for selecting a tab and increases the complexity of your app, making it harder to locate information. Although a More tab can display extra tabs, this requires additional taps and is a poor use of space. Include essential tabs only, and use the minimum tabs necessary for your information hierarchy. Too few tabs can be a problem too, as it can make your interface feel disconnected. In general, use between three and five tabs on iPhone. A few more are acceptable on iPad.

If you yet wish to present more items in your navigation, use the **More** icon on the list of Apple's [System Icons](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/system-icons/) and create a separate view with the list of additional items in their order of utility.

On the other hand, the icon like a Hamburger Menu you mention, on Apple's list of [System Icons](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/system-icons/), is used for representing **Most Viewed** items, and even that uses three horizontal bars following three dots enclosed in a rounded rectangle, placed one below the other, just like the hamburger menu icon.

Hence, I believe, the premise of your question is false in itself.